# Azure Function calling a Powershell script and unattended login

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, service-principal

I'm creating an Azure Function that will call a PowerShell script. In order to do this I need to have the PS script do an unattended login. So I created an application and Service Principal as follows:

```
# Create an Azure Active Directory Application that will be used for authentication in Powershell Automation scripts. 
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString '<MyPassword>' -AsPlainText -Force
$AzureAdApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "PowerShellAdminApp" -Password $Password -HomePage "https://www.phoenix.com" -IdentifierUris "https://www.phoenix.com"

# Create the Service Principal
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $AzureAdApplication.ApplicationId

# Add permissions to the Server Principal
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $AzureAdApplication.ApplicationId.Guid
```

This all works correctly.

Then, in my PS script(s), I will log in, unattended, as follows:

```
$Username = "https://www.phoenix.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "<MyPassword>" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username, $Password
Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -TenantId '<MyTenantId'
```

This works as well. However, I feel like I'm not understanding something or I'm missing something. This is not at all secure. If I have to have this login code in all my PS scripts, I'm basically letting anyone who has access to these scripts see the tenant Id and the password to the app. They then could perform any activity the app can perform.

Am I doing this correctly or not understanding something?

Comment: Hi, depending on where the PS script executes you could look at using the vault in Azure to store password. Also take a look at Azure MSI, if you enable on the VM then you can further secure things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use App Settings to define environment variables and store passwords there and in your code just read them:

```
$username = $env:username
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:password -AsPlainText -Force
```

Here's how to configure that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings